# Is there a way to validate the number of hosts for a group in Ansible Inventory file?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

My requirement is shown below, I have an Ansible inventory file which is divided into some groups based on the components shown below:

```
[all]

node1 
node2
node3
node4

[webapp]
node3
node4

[ui]
node1
```

Is there a way to validate the number of hosts for a group in inventory file if condition fails then playbook should not run ?

My condition is: `ui` group should always have only one host.

Ex:

```
[ui]
node1  -- condition check pass proceed with playbook execution

[ui]
node1 
node2  -- condition fails should stop playbook execution with exception 
          with ui group cannot have more than one hosts
```

Answer (score 6):

You can easily do it in a single task:

- use Ansible [magic variable `groups`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts),
- combine it with [`length` filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/) to count the number of elements in `ui` group,
- insert the above into an arithmetic comparison conditional in [`assert`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/assert_module.html) or [`fail`](http://ansible-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fail_module.html) module to verify and control the flow.

---

For example:

```
- name: Inventory validation
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - assert:
        that:
          - "groups['ui'] | length <= 1"
          - "groups['webapp'] | length <= 1"
```

But (this is based on comment) if you assign the variables first, you need to cast the value to integer in comparison:

```
- name: Inventory validation
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    UI_COUNT: "{{ groups['ui'] | length }}"
    WEBAPP_COUNT: "{{ groups['webapp'] | length }}"
  tasks:
    - assert:
        that:
          - "UI_COUNT | int <= 1"
          - "WEBAPP_COUNT | int <= 1"
```

Comment: - name: Inventory validation  
  hosts: localhost  
  gather_facts: false  
  vars:  
    UI_COUNT: "{{ groups['ui'] | length }}"  
    WEBAPP_COUNT: "{{ groups['webapp'] | length }}"  

  tasks:  
    - name: Checking  
      fail:  
        msg: "Incorrect no of hosts"  
      when:  
        - UI_COUNT > 1  
        - WEBAPP_COUNT > 1  

      assert:  
        that:  
          - "UI_COUNT > 1"    

fail or assert block gets executed even when my when condition is false, am I missing anything ?

Comment: @Vijay It's really difficult to read code inserted in a comment -- and for example your `assert` doesn't have a dash in front, so I don't know what it is at all; but most likely problem is you need to cast the value to integer: `UI_COUNT|int > 1`, and `WEBAPP_COUNT|int > 1`. Also with a list in `when` you join the conditions with logical `and`.

Comment: @Vijay See examples I added to the answer.